# C Linked list pointer problems (infinite loop)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Edit: new code added, current problem is when i insert a node it works fine, but if i insert any more than one node the insert_node method never completes, the first statement prints, saying "insert called" then it never finishes "insert complete" is never  printed.

The only thing i can think of is the while loop condition but i cant see why this would be infinite.

Also when i insert 1 node, it prints fine but it never stops printing, again another infinite loop.

Any ideas on the cause of said errors?

```
 /* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: che16
 *
 * Created on 20 November 2013, 08:59
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "structure.h"

/*
 * 
 */

node* head = NULL;
int set_head = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int no;

    printf("enter amount of books \n");

    scanf("%d", &no);

    create_books(no);
    print_list(head);


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

node* create_books(int no_of_books) {
    char title[50];
    char author[30];
    unsigned int number;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < no_of_books; i++) {
        node* new_node;
        new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof (node));
        printf("enter book title \n");
        scanf("%s", title);
        printf("enter author name \n");
        scanf("%s", author);
        printf("enter ISDN number \n");
        scanf("%10u", &number);

        strncpy(new_node->btitle, title, 40);
        strncpy(new_node->name, author, 40);

        new_node->isbn = number;
        new_node->n = NULL;

        if (!set_head) {
            head = new_node;
            insert_node(head, new_node);
            set_head = 1;
            continue;
        }
        insert_node(head, new_node);
    }
}

void insert_node(node* head, node* insert) {
    printf("insert called \n");
    insert->n = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = insert;
    } else {
        node* curr = head;

        while (curr->n != NULL) {
            curr = curr->n;
        }
        curr->n = insert;
    }
    printf("insert complete \n");

}

void delete_node(node* head, node * node) {

}

void print_list(node * head) {
    while (head) {
        printf("%s: \"%s\" (%u)\n", head->btitle, head->name, head->isbn);

        head = head->n;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have lots of memory leaks, as well as not passing e.g. `head` by reference to `insert_node`. There are probably lots of other problems too.

Comment: `n = malloc(sizeof(node);` and then `n = create_book(title, author, number);` ... So many things are wrong here...

Comment: you do the same with `curr = malloc...` then `curr = head`. You should really study the way memory is handled and how pointers are used in C. Find a good book or a good course.

Comment: right back to the drawing board for me then! the malloc stuff was added by one of my helpers for the course i am studying, only been doing c about 2 months :/

Comment: @Eregrith can you help me with this error? node* curr;
    curr->n = head; prodcudes the error "main.c:130:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]" but curr->n and head are both node pointers so shouldn't that be allowed?

Comment: The only malloc should be inside `create_book`

Comment: @Eregrith sorted that i understand what i was doing wrong with malloc now. but any idea on assignment from incompatible pointer type error as in my previous comment? why cant i do: a pointer to a node = pointer to a node

Comment: I never found your line `curr->n = head`. Also be careful not to put spaces inside `xxx->yyy`, around the arrow.

Comment: void print_list(node* head) {

    node* curr;
    curr->n = head; this is the line extract of the code where i am getting the error

Comment: Your "next" pointers "n" (not a very good name BTW) is uninitialized so assuming your insertion code is ok, the tail will point to junk.

Comment: On your updated code: You have avoided passing a pointer to the local variable `head` by making `head` a global. That's okay, if a bit unflexible, but if you do that, you shouldn't pass `head` to `insert_node`: Inside that function, the symbol `head` refers to the local copy, not the global `head`. The local symbol `head` "shadows" the global, i.e. it makes it inaccessible. If `set_head` is 0, you call `insert_node` twice. That's probably not waht you intended. Whether a head exists or not is taken care of inside `insert_node`. Delete `set_head` and just call `insert_node` unconditionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, you allocate too much memory. The temporary local variables are just pointers into existent memory. The only place where you want to allocate memory is in `create_book`, where you create data. You'll have to `free` that memory by deleting the nodes later. (I think you might be confused by the different roles that pointers play: Sometimes they just identify newly allocated memory, more often they are used to access and traverse already existing memory.)

Next, `head` isn't a node in its own right, it's just a pointer to the first node. If there are no nodes, this pointer is `NULL`. This is true at the beginning of the program, which means you have to initialise it:

```
node* head = NULL;
```

But it's also true if all books have been removed from the list. Obviously, if you add your first node or if you remove the first node, the `head` changes. Your `insert_node` should take care of these changes. One way to do so is to pass the head as pointer to a node pointer.

(In C, everything passed as argument is a local copy. Changing is will leave the original value in the calling function unchanged. But if you pass a pointer, the pointed-to stuff is the same in both the calling and the called function. You can change that via the poiner.)

Also, whether the `head` needs to be changed should be the concern of `insert_node`, not of the calling (*client*) code in `main`. If you skip all the wrong mallocs, the insertion is much easier:

```
void insert_node(node **head, node* insert)
{
    insert->n = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = insert;
    } else {
        node* curr = *head;

        while (curr->n) curr = curr->n;
        curr->n = insert;
    }
}
```

You can call this from `main` unconditionally like so:

```
insert_node(&head, create_book(title, author, number));
```

Note how all that also makes `head_set` redundant: If the `head` is set, it has a legal pointer value, otherwise it is `NULL`.

The compiler error that complains about the incompatible pointer occurs, because the structure has no name. In C, a structure type is defined by the word `struct` and then its name. Some people think that the `struct` keyword is unnecessary and `typedef` the struct to a single-word type. You do this in a single statement. You could declare:

```
typedef struct node {
    char btitle[40];
    char name[40];
    unsigned int isbn;
    struct node* n;
} node;
```

or you could separate type and struct:

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node {
    char btitle[40];
    char name[40];
    unsigned int isbn;
    struct node* n;
};
```

(The `typedef` might go into the header and the struct in the main source file.)

You'll notice that I've changed `char *btitle` to `char btitle[40]`. If you just store a pointer to the title, you essentially store a pointer to your local buffer `title` in `main`. This buffer is used for input in the loop and at the time the books are printed that buffer contains the value of the third book. That means that all books in the list will have the same name and author.

One way to solve this is to copy the contents of the buffers pointed to into the struct, which must, of course provide memory for its buffers, as shown above. Your `create_book` becomes:

```
node* create_book(char* t, char* auth, unsigned int num)
{
    node* new_node;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof (node));

    strncpy(new_node->btitle, t, 40);
    strncpy(new_node->name, auth, 40);
    new_node->isbn = num;
    new_node->n = NULL;

    return new_node;
}
```

The routine `strncpy` copies at most 40 characters from the second buffer to the first. You should include `<string.h>` for the prototype. Also note that I initialise the pointer to the next node, `n` explicitly to `NULL`, as I've done with `head` in main. The next-node pointer is either `NULL` or a pointer to a valid node at all times.

Now that insertion works, printing the list is easy:

```
void print_list(node* head)
{
    while (head) {
        printf("%s: \"%s\" (%u)\n", head->btitle, head->name, head->isbn);

        head = head->n;
    }
}
```

See how the code only uses data contained in the nodes themselves and how `head == NULL` or just `head` fo short is used as a handy criterion that the end of the list is reached. (The `print_node` function does not rquire to pass `head` as pointer to node pointer, because it never changes the list, just inspects its data.)

There are still issues to address like deleting the nodes (or the while list) after use and how to handle unsuccessful allocations, but with these changes, your code should at least compile and run.

Comment: WOW! quality response thanks a lot! my code does now runs but i have changed my code a bit since this and when i insert the first node it works fine, but when i insert a second node after that it calls the insert method you provided but it never finishes it, so there is an inifinate loop somewhere